# VBA Module: Use the function "Intersect" for multiples ranges

Tags: vba, excel, intersect

I would like to get some feedback how to write my desired VBA module. 
In my file I have multiple columns in which the values are changing as new data is collected from an external source (Bloomberg). Next, I would like to get a message if one of the values within these ranges is larger than the product of two cells who are always the same ($A$1 and $A$2). In addition, I have multiple sheets, so I would like to make sure that the module applies for every sheet.

After searching the internet and Stackoverflow I came up with two alternatives:

The first alternative:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
With Sh
    Set r1 = Sh.Range("N1:N50")
    Set r2 = Sh.Range("AA1:AA50")
    Set r3 = Sh.Range("AN1:AN50")
    Set r4 = Sh.Range("BA1:BA50")
    Set r5 = Sh.Range("BN1:BN50")
    Set r6 = Sh.Range("CA1:CA50")
    Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6)
    Dim myMultipleRange as Range
    Dim Cell as Range
    For Each Cell in myMultipleRange.Cells
    With Cell
    If .Value2 > 0.1 * $A$1 * $A$2 Then
    MsgBox ("Ticker: " & Sh.Name & ", Today's volume in the " & Cells(row,column -1) " & " serie is  " & Cells" & " contracts")
```

However, as I explore the internet I see similar questions where the answers include the "Intersect"-function. I understand that Intersect  will return a Range Object that represents the intersection of two, or more, ranges. However, what is exactly the difference with my module? And which method is faster? I want the fastest module as my file is huge!

I tried to write a second module with the Intersect function

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
With Sh
    Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, my MultipleRange as Range
    Set r1 = Sh.Range("N1:N50")
    Set r2 = Sh.Range("AA1:AA50")
    Set r3 = Sh.Range("AN1:AN50")
    Set r4 = Sh.Range("BA1:BA50")
    Set r5 = Sh.Range("BN1:BN50")
    Set r6 = Sh.Range("CA1:CA50")
    Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6)
    If Target.Value > (0.1 * sh.Range("A1").Value * sh.Range("A2").Value 
    If Not Intersect(Target, myMultipleRange) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Ticker: " & Sh.Name & ", Today's volume in the " & Cells(row,column -1) " & " serie is  " & Cells" & " contracts
```

Which set-up do you prefer and do you see room for improvements?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Only the first approach will work (once all the errors are removed). Yet, that's not the fastest approach. The fastest approach would be an array. Afterwards the array should be searched for all possible "matches" and then they should be shown (if multiple occurrences then all at once) in a message box. I suggest that you write a working sub and then post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for improvements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you push me into a direction with the errors?And, ideally, I would like a message box notification for each occurrence. Should I still follow your advice in this case? Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'll hope those examples were just intended as pseudo code and show you a solution. If that was intended as valid VBA code, please see my notes on the errors below

```
Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ' Assign range to an array for speed, could just use the range object in a similar way
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Set myRange = Sh.Range("N1:N50,AA1:AA50,AN1:AN50,BA1:BA50,BN1:BN50,CA1:CA50")
    myArray = myRange.Cells
    ' Just calculate the product once
    Dim product As Double
    product = Sh.Range("A1").Value * Sh.Range("A2").Value
    ' Loop through range, message if value is greater than product
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        If myArray(n, 1) > product Then
            MsgBox "Sheet name: " & Sh.Name & ", Cell address: " & myRange.Cells(n).Address
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Note you don't need anything to do with intersection or union of ranges, just list them all in one range object...

Popping up multiple message boxes is pretty user-unfriendly, especially if your "file is huge" and there are potentially many of them. I would advise storing all of the desired addresses in a string, then outputting the one string somewhere in your workbook.

---

**Errors**: There are other minor issues, but each of these issues would cause your sub to have a fatal error.

- You must end subs, with blocks and ifs with the relevant `End Sub`, `End With`, `End If`.
- Must end for loops with `Next loopvariable`.
- Using variables which you haven't defined like `row` and `column`.
- Trying to access range values by just stating their address like `$A$1` when it should be `Sh.Range("A1").Value`
- `MsgBox` doesn't take a string in parentheses unless you are assigning the returned value to something, just use `MsgBox "my message"` not `MsgBox ("my message")`
- When using `With Sh`, you don't have to start anything with `Sh.`, just use `.`, like `Set r1 = .Range("A1")`. This wouldn't cause an error, but makes the `With` pointless.